# How to solve this differential equation for distributions?

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations, distribution-theory

> Let $ f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^{2n} (n!)^{-2} $. Solve the equation $$ (f(x)-1) \: u'(x) = 0 $$ for $ u \in D' $. That is, what distributions u satisfy this equation?

I'm not quite sure about how to approach such a problem and would be grateful for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's obvious from the construction of $f$ that $f$ is convex and even, and therefore takes it minimum at $x=0$. We have $f(0)=1$, $f'(0)=0$ and $f''(0)=2$, so $f(x)-1$ has a double zero at $x=0$, and is non-zero everywhere else.

This means that the equation is equivalent to $x^2 \, u'(x) = 0$ which has solutions $u(x) = AH + B\delta + C,$ where $A,B,C$ are constants, $H$ is the Heaviside function, and $\delta$ of course is the Dirac delta distribution.

Comment: Thanks your your answer! Could you explain to me why exactly $ x^2 \, u'(x) = 0 $ is equivalent to $ (f(x)-1) \: u'(x) = 0 $ with regards to the "distribution solution"? I understand that $ (f(x)-1) $ has a shape similar to the one of $ x^2 $, yet they're not the same. Why are they interchangeable in the differential equation, though?

Comment: We can write the equation as $x^2 \, h(x) \, u(x) = 0$ where $h\in C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$, $h(0)=1$, $h'(0)=0$, and $h(x) \neq 0$ for all $x$. Thus, $h(x) \, u(x) = A \delta(x) + B \delta'(x)$ and 
$$u(x) = \frac{1}{h(x)} (A\delta(x)+B\delta'(x))=A\delta(x) + B\delta'(x).$$

Comment: You should verify this by expanding $\frac{1}{h(x)}\delta'(x)$.